# Imported data from XML not treated as number

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I have imported some prices with `importXml`. I stripped all the text to leave just the number in the cell (I even replaced the comma with a dot as with my locale Google Spreadsheets likes dots for decimals).

But the prices are not treated as numbers. If It try to sum them, they're not summed. If I select Euro as currency, the symbol is not added.

See live example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1shbGRkYaBV9QvpwfNRDKs4NPHbwHOHLugUyUgAOdFKU/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see the `small` function doens't work.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying each of the imported prices by 1? This sometimes forces the cell format to change to number.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your formula or any of your cells with the numbers with a "value" function, assuming your number values are in A1 through A5, if you want to sum the range of these imported numbers try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VALUE(A1:A5)))
```